# Python: how to round float to x total digits?

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I'm **not** talking about x **decimal** digits.

examples with 3 digits:

```
1.2345 -> 1.23
12.345 -> 12.3
123.45 -> 123.0
1234.5 -> 1230
12345 -> 12300
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val = list(i[:-2 - (i.find('.') > 3)] + '00')
if i.find('.') > -1:
    val[i.find('.')] = '.'
print(float(''.join(val)))
```